# Getting user ip address and checking if ill allow him to vote again php

Tags: php, ip

I have an application with images that people can vote, and I want to check the ip of the user to disallow him to vote for a second time. What is the best approach for this, should I get the ip and fill in a .txt file and every time a user tries to vote ill check that file and if the ip is not in the file allow him?? or is there a better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the user's like this:

```
$users_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Don't use text files (as this will be bad for your HDD, too much I/O); instead use database.

When user arrives at the vote script:

- Check if this IP has a record in your db table
- If the IP has a record, check when the user last voted and compare with current time
- If the timespan from his last vote > what it should be, let him vote, update db table for that ip "last_vote"
- If the user doesn't have a record in db (first vote); insert a db table row with the ip and current timestamp

Comment: thanks looks like a solid solution only you have an extra info. if the user voted, he cannot vote again, which i guess makes my life easier :), ill just put the ip in a database, and check if the ip has a record in the db, if it has ill notify the user he already voted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also store cookie for a time interval. if a user vote for a question then save a particular cookie for that question like .

```
setcookie('voted'.$_POST['qid'], 'yes', time() + 4800 , "/");
```

If question is new then user can vote.

Comment: cookie based validation is bad idea. user's can skip/bypass it by using a different browser or using Private Mode (FireFox) or Incognito (Chrome).